# How to display the saved input value from the db without refreshing the web page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote a code that enables me to post an input value (using AngularJS 1.3.5 $http.post) and save it into a db then display it in my html page. To get the new input value after clicking on save I have to refresh the page to display it. I must find a solution without using php and jQuery. I saw an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629265/angularjs-form-with-and-without-refresh): changing from $http.post to $xhr.post wasn't possible may be it's caused by the angularJs version I am using. What should I do?

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
  <input ng-model="stack"></input>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
<p>{{stack}}</p> 
</form>
$scope.save = function(url, data1) {
            /* post to server */
            $http({
                url : url,
                data : {
                    "stack" : data1
                },
                method : "POST",
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }
            }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.stack = data.stack;
            }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status + ' ' + headers;
            });

        };
```

Notice that I am displaying the input value in my html page from the backend.

Comment: Give us more code please, like your controller code ...

Comment: isn't the new input value same as u sent it earlier , you can display that only.
otherwise make a new ajax call in success handler of save() call

Comment: @ArnaudGueras I updated my question

Comment: What is the data returned by data.stack? Are you sure it has the updated data?

Comment: @BonMacalindong  data.stack returns the input value to post to the backend

Answer (score 3):

Bind the get call inside a function and call that function inside the same controller, this will update data without refresh.

```
  $scope.getData = function() {
        $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : '/getData'         //any url
        }).then(function(response) {
            //success code

        })
    }
    $scope.getData();
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. The call of get method in the controller caused an access allow control error. I updated my question with my controller code

Comment: Are you returning the updated object from the backend?

Comment: yeah after inserting it in the db I used the select request to call it from the db and get it in the web service and finally display it

Comment: So you are making a get call in the frontend? can you show me the get call?

Comment: app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('Url')
            .success(function(data) {
              return data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
              return err;
            });
}]);

Comment: modify something like this
app.factory('myapp', [ '$http', function($http) {
 return {
  method : function($scope) {
   $http.get('Url').success(function(data) {
    $scope.stack=data;
   }).error(function(err) {
    $scope.stack=err;
   });
  }
 }
} ]);
and call it like this in your controller and inject $scope into it myapp.method($scope)

Comment: I got many parsing errors when I did this. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: Welcome. What technology are you using in the backend. ?What kind of errors its showing?

Comment: I am using java in the backend. here are the errors:
angular.js:11500 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20myapp
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:38:22
    at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js:36:49)
etc....

Comment: There might be some serialization problem when you are making get call.

Comment: In fact my factory and my controllers are in two different files and I am parsing three different json files :
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
    function getLists() {
        var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
        var list = [];
        for(i=0; i<tab.length; i++){
        $http.get(tab[i]) 
            .then(function(res) {
                list.push(res.data);
            });
        }
        return list;
    }

    return {
        getLists: getLists
    };
]);

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for it ?

Comment: Did u get the solution?

Comment: not yet I was not online I will create now a plnkr :)

Comment: Yeah sure waiting for it.

Comment: I followed your method and now it automatically refresh the whole page. I made a progress! I hope that I will find as soon as possible a solution to get a partial refresh  thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Make your request return the new data

Step 2: Use that data to replace the old data

Since you didn't provide much info about how the structure is I'll try to be generic as possible. Assuming you're updating a product and fetching its new price:

```
$scope.product = {
    name: 'Pop Rocks',
    price: 1.99 // can be changed from an input with `ngModel` or something
};

$scope.save = function() {
    // post new price
    $http.post('/api/products', $scope.product).then(function(response) {
        // response.data contains the JSON object for he product,
        // with new price/name/etc
        product = JSON.parse(response.data) // parse it into an object
        $scope.product = product // replace old $scope.product with new product
    });
}

$scope.doublePrice = function() {
    // using this will update the new price immediately -in the view-,
    // just to show you how binding works. It will not update DB
    $scope.product.price *= 2;
}
```

Assuming your view has something similar to this:

```
<strong>Price:</strong> {{ product.price | currency:"$" }}
```

Your changes should reflect thanks to 2 way binding!

Comment: thank you for your answer I tried to follow the steps but still have the same problem. I updated my question with the controller code

Comment: Does your `data.stack` actually hold the data you need? It should work. Try wrapping the assignment with a `$timeout` call (`$timeout(function() { $scope.stack = data.stack})`)

Comment: yeah it should hold the data to post to my web service . I tried with $timeout but I still have the same problem